# Why my 3d Object in HoloLens follow me all the time and not stable?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, hololens-emulator

In my Project, using the MRTK, Vision LIB and HoloLens 2. when I transfer my project to HoloLens the problem is that for example I have a Slate(Panel) it appears but it follow my head all the time, it s not stable in one position. before was everything good , I don't know what it happens or what maybe I've changed by mistake. These are my Settings :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lu8dq.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKK9u.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpnPd.jpg)

I am using unity 2019.4.3f1
Vision lib 2.0.2
MRTK 2.5.0

I hope if someone can help me, Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The script `FollowMeToggle` is used for exactly that. Remove the component and try again.

If that does not fix it, check the position of your GameObject in the hirarchy. If your slate is positioned under the MainCamera, then such a behaviour would be expected. If that is the case, place your GameObject directly under the Scene.

Comment: i tried but same thing :(( i dont know maybe i have changed something in mixed reality toolkit by camera and input ,,, do you know which configuration should i use ?

Comment: I understand the Problem now, I have deleted vision lib SDK package and vision lib HoloLens SDK package also I have deleted all XR plugins and then it works well but the problem now that I need to use vision lib for tracking and with vision lib SDK there is legacy input helpers package which I guess it causes the problem ....

Comment: Apparently there is [version 2.0](https://visionlib.com/develop/downloads/) of VisionLib, you should probably check the [installation instructions](https://docs.visionlib.com/v2.0.0/_packages_overview.html) or the [migration guide](https://docs.visionlib.com/v2.0.0/vl_unity_s_d_k_migration_guide.html) and try again.